# I would like to execute code with a database query

Tags: java, mysql, database

I would like to make a mysql database query in a Java code and if the value from the database is true for example then a certain code should be executed and if the value is false the program should close but I have the problem that I get the value from the database is not formatted so that I can make an IF query. if I could not explain this in a very understandable way, I hope that you can find out from the code in the appendix

```
//imports



    package de.alphaalmann.troll;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
    import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
    import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;



    import java.sql.*;

    public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//databaseconnetion

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/plugin?useJDBC";
            String user = "plugin";
            String password = "uwu3000";

            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {

                System.out.println("sucsesful");



                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT STATUS FROM plugin WHERE NAME="trollpl"");
                stmt.execute();

                System.out.println(stmt);
                stmt.close();
//if-query if it true,

                if(stmt==true) {
                    //if it true execute this


    //else this part

                }else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }


                        }catch(SQLException ex) {

                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }


        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

highling.

You'll need a ResultSet object in order to receive the query results, get the results and then close the PreparedStatement.

Something like this:

```
int result;
ResultSet rs = stmt.execute();
if(rs.next()){
   // I don't know what your query returns
   //I'll assume you use only the first result , it'll be an int 
  result = rs.getInt(1);
}
stmt.close();
// Now you decide what to do with result.
```

HTH,

WB::